# Sign out of Ubuntu single sign-on account in software center reviews

Tags: 11.04, software-center, single-sign-on

Will the Ubuntu Software Center get an option to sign out of your Ubuntu single sign-on account?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm reading in the [Software Center Specifications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter/RatingsAndReviews), and from what I'm seeing as I'm exploring the Ubuntu Software Center on Natty (11.04), the answer is "No".